# Define manually routes using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I want to define routes manually to some method of classes, something like this :

```
class X:

    def route1():
       #do stuff here

    def route2():
       #do stuff here
```

and then make something like this :

```
app.add_url_rule('/x/', view_func=X.route1())
app.add_url_rule('/y/', view_func=X.route2())
```

It's possible?? What's the correct way to acomplish this?

Comment: Its not very clear if you are having problem, but i would go with the flask-classy extension. Basically are Django Class Based Views for flask (well, they are a bit more than just that, but anyway)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are several ways to do this:

1. Create a global instance of your class and route your rules to it:

   ```
   class X(object):
       # Your code here

   INSTANCE_X = X()

   # Note that we are not *calling* the methods
   app.add_url_rule('/x/', view_func=INSTANCE_X.route1)
   app.add_url_rule('/y/', view_func=INSTANCE_X.route2)
   ```
2. Create an instance in the view function and delegate to it:

   ```
   # Using both methods of registering URLs here
   # just to show that both work

   @app.route('/x/')
   def handle_route1():
       return X().route1()

   def handle_route2():
       return X().route2()

   app.add_url_rule('/y/', view_func=handle_route2)
   ```
3. Inherit from Flask's [`View`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.views.View) or [`MethodView`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.views.MethodView) [Pluggable View](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/) classes and use the [`as_view` classmethod](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.views.View.as_view) to handle this for you:

   ```
   class X(View):
       methods = ['GET']

       def dispatch_request(self):
           if request.path == '/x/':
               return route1()
           elsif request.path == '/y/':
               return route2()
           else:
               abort(404)

   app.add_url_rule('/x/', view_func=X.as_view('X.route1'))
   app.add_url_rule('/y/', view_func=X.as_view('X.route2'))
   ```

Comment: Which of these methods is most correct is going to depend on your circumstances.  I prefer using what is provided, so if I was working with new code I would almost always go with #3.

Answer (score 6):

Like I said in the comments, do you know [flask-classy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Classy/)?

From their exemple:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.classy import FlaskView

# we'll make a list to hold some quotes for our app
quotes = [
    "A noble spirit embiggens the smallest man! ~ Jebediah Springfield",
    "If there is a way to do it better... find it. ~ Thomas Edison",
    "No one knows what he can do till he tries. ~ Publilius Syrus"
]

app = Flask(__name__)

class QuotesView(FlaskView):

    def index(self):
        return "<br>".join(quotes)

    def get(self, id):
        id = int(id)
        if id < len(quotes) - 1:
            return quotes[id]
        else:
            return "Not Found", 404     

QuotesView.register(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Would generate automatically routes for `http://foobar.foo/quotes` and `http://foobar.foo/quotes/<id>`

Comment: `flask.ext` is deprecated: https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1135#issuecomment-61860862

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `flask`'s helper decorator, `app.route(...)`, don't forget, it's just a decorator, and you can always just `call` the returned wrapper of a decorator.

With a nonsense, do-nothing wrapper like,

```
def some_wrapper():
    def wrapper(fn):
        return fn()
    return wrapper
```

When you wrap a func like,

```
@some_wrapper
def some_func():
    print('Hello World')
```

For all intents and purposes, what might as well be happening is,

```
def some_func():
    print('Hello World')

some_func = some_wrapper()(some_func)
```

So, because of that, you can call `app.route` just like you can any decorator,

```
app.route('/x/')(X.route1)
```

This ends up doing exactly the same as @sean-vieira's bit of his answer - `app.add_url_rule('/x/', view_func=INSTANCE_X.route1)`.

But one reason you might prefer it is because it follows the "regular" path of flask, and flask docs.

For my use, the reason I use it is to chain some routes which I add programatically,

```
suffix = 'ducky'

app.route(f'secure_initial_route_for_{suffix}', endpoint=f'secure_{suffix}')(
    roles_required('admin')(secured_fn))
app.route(f'secure_sub_route_for_{suffix}', endpoint=f'secure_sub_{suffix}')(
    roles_required('admin')(secured_sub_fn))
```

That is how I some of my use cases.